# How to plot perturbations of a implicit equation obtained from Eliminate

Tags: plotting

Suppose we have parametrized curve $\gamma(t)$. For instance, consider $\gamma(t)$ as the folium

```
folium[t_] := {3 t/(1 + t^3), 3 t^2/(1 + t^3)}
```

Then we obtained the Cartesian equation $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ of $\gamma$ using `Eliminate`.

In our example

```
foliumimplicit := Eliminate[{x, y}==folium[t],t]
```

gives us $x^3-3xy=-y^3$.

I would like to plot perturbations $f(x,y)=g(x,y)+\varepsilon$ of the implicit equation obtained. $x^3-3xy=-y^3+\varepsilon$ of the `foliumimplicit` equation obtained.

For our example, when $\varepsilon=0.1,-0.1$ the graphs of the $x^3-3xy=-y^3+\varepsilon$ are

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking for `ContourPlot`?

Comment: My question was to try to create a program or function that has a parametrized curve as an input and give us the plots of perturbations of the cartesian equations of the curve (like in the example above of the folium).  Hope now is clear my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to plot your curve is as a collection of contour plots with different values of e:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[x^3 - 3 x y == e - y^3, {e, -0.1, 0.1, 0.05}]], 
            {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or simply draw several contours on the same graph: `ContourPlot[x^3 - 3 x y + y^3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> Range[-0.1, 0.1, 0.05], ColorFunction -> (White &)]`